Button Command not firing in UserControl WPF MVVM
I have a button command that is binded to a RelayCommand AddCommand whose code is located in my MainViewModel.cs. The problem I'm facing is the button I need the command to fire in is located in a usercontrol SettingsView.xaml.
When I bind the command to a button in my MainWindow.xaml, the ObservableCollection<PanelButton> PanelButton is udpated properly on click, but once I add the button command to a button in my SettingsView.xaml the event never fires.
Here is my MainViewModel.cs.
        public ObservableCollection<PanelButton> PanelButton { get; set; }

        public RelayCommand HomeViewCommand { get; set; }

        public RelayCommand SettingsViewCommand { get; set; }

        public RelayCommand AddCommand => new RelayCommand(execute => AddNavigationPanel());

        public StartingHomeViewModel HomeVM { get; set; }

        public SettingsViewModel SettingsVM { get; set; }

        private object _currentView;

        public object CurrentView
        {
            get { return _currentView; }
            set
            {
                _currentView = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }

        }

        private PanelButton selectedPanelButton;

        public PanelButton SelectedPanelButton
        {
            get { return selectedPanelButton; }
            set 
            { 
                selectedPanelButton = value; 
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public MainViewModel()
        {

            PanelButton = new ObservableCollection<PanelButton>();
            panelHandler = new PanelHandler();

            HomeVM = new StartingHomeViewModel();
            SettingsVM = new SettingsViewModel();

            CurrentView = HomeVM;

            HomeViewCommand = new RelayCommand(o =>
            {
                CurrentView = HomeVM;
            });

            SettingsViewCommand = new RelayCommand(o =>
            {
                CurrentView = SettingsVM;
            });


            ShowNavigationPanels();
        }

        private void ShowNavigationPanels()
        {
            foreach (string name in panelHandler.PanelNameCollection())
            {
                PanelButton.Add(new PanelButton
                {
                    Name = name
                });
            }
        }

        private void AddNavigationPanel()
        {
            MessageBox.Show("it works", "success", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Exclamation);

            panelHandler.CreatePanel("test panel 1");
            PanelButton.Add(new PanelButton
            {
                Name = "test panel 1"
            });

        }

Here is my MainWindow.xaml
                    <Window.DataContext>
                        <viewModel:MainViewModel/>
                    </Window.DataContext>

                    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding PanelButton}">
                        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <RadioButton Style="{StaticResource MenuButtonTheme}"
                                             Content="{Binding Name}"
                                             Height="50"
                                             FontSize="14"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl>

                    <ContentControl Grid.Row="1"
                            Grid.Column="1"
                            Margin="0"
                            Padding="5"
                            Content="{Binding CurrentView}"/>

Here is my SettingsView.xaml
    <UserControl.DataContext>
        <viewmodel:MainViewModel/>
    </UserControl.DataContext>

<Button Background="white"
        Height="30"
        Width="200"
        HorizontalAlignment="Left"
        Margin="10,10,0,0"
        Content="Create"
        Style="{StaticResource RegularButton}"
        Command="{Binding AddCommand}"/>

Here is my App.xaml
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Theme/MenuButtonTheme.xaml"/>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Theme/SearchTheme.xaml"/>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Theme/RegularButtonTheme.xaml"/>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Theme/ScrollbarTheme.xaml"/>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Theme/SettingsTabTheme.xaml"/>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Theme/PanelNavigationTheme.xaml"/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModel:StartingHomeViewModel}">
                <view:StartingHomeView/>
            </DataTemplate>

            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModel:SettingsViewModel}">
                <view:SettingsView/>
            </DataTemplate>

        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>

EDIT
I added DataContext to SettingsView, which now fires the event which brings another problem. The event fires, prompting the messagebox, but now the ObservableCollection<PanelButton> PanelButton doesn't update when fired. Any ideas why this might be happening?

Judging by the XAML code, you create two different instances of MainViewModel. One for the window and the second for the UserControl SettingsView.
The command is called in your instance for SettingsView, but it cannot affect the window that is bound to another instance.
Also, your data template is completely unclear. Judging by its code, SettingsView should receive viewModel:SettingsViewModel in the data context, and not MainViewModel. Such an assignment breaks the entire logic of using <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModel:SettingsViewModel}">.
Without seeing the entire code and not understanding your task as a whole, I will offer solutions based on my guesses.

Using a single instance of MainViewModel in App resources

    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Theme/MenuButtonTheme.xaml"/>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Theme/SearchTheme.xaml"/>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Theme/RegularButtonTheme.xaml"/>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Theme/ScrollbarTheme.xaml"/>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Theme/SettingsTabTheme.xaml"/>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Theme/PanelNavigationTheme.xaml"/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

           <viewModel:MainViewModel x:Key="mainVM"/>

            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModel:StartingHomeViewModel}">
                <view:StartingHomeView/>
            </DataTemplate>

            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModel:SettingsViewModel}">
                <view:SettingsView/>
            </DataTemplate>

        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>

MainWindow.xaml
<Window x:Class="....MainWindow"
        --------------
        --------------
        DataContext="{DynamicResource mainVM}">
    <!--<Window.DataContext>
        <viewModel:MainViewModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>-->

SettingsView.xaml
    <!--<UserControl.DataContext>
        <viewmodel:MainViewModel/>
    </UserControl.DataContext>-->

<Button Background="white"
        Height="30"
        Width="200"
        HorizontalAlignment="Left"
        Margin="10,10,0,0"
        Content="Create"
        Style="{StaticResource RegularButton}"
        Command="{Binding AddCommand, Source={StaticResource mainVM}}"/>


Using RoutedCommand

    public static partial class SomeHelper
    {
        public static readonly RoutedUICommand AddCommand = new RoutedUICommand("Some text: Add command for...", nameof(AddCommand), typeof(SomeHelper));
        static SomeHelper()
        {
            CommandManager.RegisterClassCommandBinding(typeof(MainWindow), new CommandBinding(
                AddCommand,
                (sender, e) =>
                {
                    MainWindow window = (MainWindow)sender;
                    MainViewModel viewModel = (MainViewModel)window.DataContext;
                    viewModel.AddCommand.Execute(e.Parameter);
                }));
        }
    }

The MainWindow.xaml code from your question can be left unchanged.
SettingsView.xaml code
    <!--<UserControl.DataContext>
        <viewmodel:MainViewModel/>
    </UserControl.DataContext>-->

<Button Background="white"
        Height="30"
        Width="200"
        HorizontalAlignment="Left"
        Margin="10,10,0,0"
        Content="Create"
        Style="{StaticResource RegularButton}"
        Command="{x:Static local:SomeHelper.AddCommand}"/>

SomeHelper is not a mandatory class. For example, SettingsView can be in a separate assembly and "will not know" about MainWindow. Therefore, in practice, there may be such an implementation:
SettingsView.xaml.cs - here the command are created
    public partial class SettingsView : UserControl
    {

        public static readonly RoutedUICommand AddCommand = new RoutedUICommand("Some text: Add command for...", nameof(AddCommand), typeof(SettingsView));

SettingsView.xaml - using command in button
<Button ---------------------
        ---------------------
        Command="{x:Static local:SettingsView.AddCommand}"/>

MainWindow.xaml.cs - adding a command handler
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        static MainWindow()
        {
            CommandManager.RegisterClassCommandBinding(typeof(MainWindow), new CommandBinding(
                SettingsView.AddCommand,
                (sender, e) =>
                {
                    MainWindow window = (MainWindow)sender;
                    MainViewModel viewModel = (MainViewModel)window.DataContext;
                    viewModel.AddCommand.Execute(e.Parameter);
                }));
        }


"Offer solutions based on my guesses"... you sir are a Godsend. You're first solution did the trick. Thank you!!!

@bccode
I still dare to suggest you try the second method. RoutedCommad is the only class implementing ICommand, which is available in the default .Net libraries for WPF. Even if you don't need it for this task, the ability to use it can still be of great help in the future, in other tasks. In my answer, I added another example of implementation on Routed Command.
